# why react dev server use https automatically?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to debug my react app built by `create-react-app` on mobile.
So I started app using `react-script start`,
and made sure all devices have same ip and port. But then the error came out when I tried to access `react dev server` on smartphone, and all I could see was just blank page.
I never use `react-script` options like `HTTPS=true`, but it seems like trying to request using `HTTPS`. Why?
This is a screenshot from android phone.

[image]

and this is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.1.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^10.0.17",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.0.20",
    "@juggle/resize-observer": "^3.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.5.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.4.1",
    "@n8tb1t/use-scroll-position": "^1.0.43",
    "@react-hook/media-query": "^1.1.1",
    "antd": "^4.2.5",
    "auth0-js": "^9.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "d3-ease": "^1.0.6",
    "emotion": "^9.2.12",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "fast-deep-equal": "^2.0.1",
    "formik": "^1.5.8",
    "formik-effect": "^1.2.0",
    "i18next": "^17.0.14",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^3.0.3",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.1.2",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.10.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "react-countup": "^4.2.2",
    "react-currency-input": "^1.3.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dropdown-tree-select": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.12",
    "react-emotion": "^9.2.12",
    "react-flags-select": "^1.1.10",
    "react-ga": "^2.7.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.4",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-highcharts": "^16.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^10.12.3",
    "react-iamport": "0.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-images": "^0.5.17",
    "react-map-gl": "^5.2.5",
    "react-materialize": "^3.3.1",
    "react-moment": "^0.7.7",
    "react-move": "^6.4.0",
    "react-paginate": "^6.3.0",
    "react-password-strength": "^2.4.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0-rc.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.50",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-share": "^3.0.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.11.0",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.11.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "react-treebeard": "^3.2.4",
    "react-typed": "^1.1.2",
    "react-use-measure": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-actions": "^2.6.5",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "universal-cookie": "^3.1.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.27.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:dev": "env-cmd -f ./.env.dev react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f ./.env.prod react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try restarting your application. The default behaviour is 'Http'

Comment: Also, can you add the script section of your package.json?

Comment: I restarted it already, but nothing changed..

Comment: Am curious, how are you trying to access the app off your android? Are you using the `on-the-same-network` link provided after the dev server starts.

Comment: no I'm just using IP from ifconfig. All devices are in the same wifi LAN